You Shall Stay Here Forever! (aka chat auto leave isn't working anymore)
Normally, after joining a chat room in Stack Exchange, if you close the browser tab (or window) the chat will trigger auto leave after a short while, think it was up to 15 minutes.
However, this appears to be broken now, and it's not being triggered even after 6-8 hours, causing anyone who joined a chat room to still be in the room even after closing the tab.
Tested with my sock 7 hours ago:

Closed the browser window right after that, and yet it's still there in the room:

Note that in addition to closing the window of the sock account, I also made sure I don't have it open in any other device, neither any other chat room anywhere. This has always triggered auto leave before.

I was going to make a hotel California reference

My prior experience with this is that auto-leave only happened when all tabs to that chat server were closed, or the browser was closed. I've definitely experienced times when chat doesn't auto-leave merely when the tab for that room is closed, but when other tabs are open to rooms on that chat server. Are you sure that what you describe is a change in function? [Note: there are a variety of chat issues at the moment, at least: Feeds not working, new messages not being added to search, so additional things could be the general degradation.]

Note that this could also be a symptom of the general WebSocket issues which SE has had since switching to Cloudlare, depending on when this started (if it's an actual change).

@Makyen Yes, we are sure. What you described has been the behaviour for a long time, and it’s a very good one. There’s definitely a bug going on these days. It’s affecting everyone I’ve interacted with across MSE rooms, and other people I regularly see. For instance, last activity from people 16 hours ago, yet still in the rooms. They usually close their tabs/computers in that time.

@Makyen thanks, I've added this info to the bug report.

More information is needed here. We are currently experiencing a few issues which appear to be happening on chat.SO and chat.MSE, but not chat.SE. On which server(s) have you tested?

Related: No inbox notifications for chat pings (Occurred at the same time)

@Makyen I tested only here on MSE. Looks like something is off/disabled/broken on this specific chat server, which causing several different bugs.
